# django circular import on urls

Tags: python, django

I have a simple django project

structure is

```
examp-
    exam
    polls
    templates
```

exam was the name of the project and polls is the name of the first app

I have the following code in exam/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/',include('polls.urls')),
]
```

and the following code in polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from views.polls import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and i am getting the following error when i try to runserver

The included URLconf module 'polls.urls from
'/home/grr/Documents/examp/polls/urls.py'>' does not appear to have
any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the
issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in polls/urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And put index function in polls/views.py

Comment: Thanks! Now it is working fine. Can you please tell me two words about my mistake?

Comment: When you do `from . import views` you are looking for a views file in your current folder. If it is other app folder then `from app_name import views`

Comment: in your case you should use `path('', index, name='index')` instead of `path('', views.index, name='index'),`

Answer (score 0):

with considering above answer code , and changing the first line using nameapp instead of "." without any error i could run my code successfully

```
from nameapp import views
```